# Which JSON module can I use in Python 2.5?

Tags: python, json

I would like to use Python's [JSON](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) module. It was only introduced in Python 2.6 and I'm stuck with 2.5 for now. Is the particular JSON module provided with Python 2.6 available as a separate module that can be used with 2.5?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41466431/pip-install-json-fails-on-ubuntu/41466452#41466452

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can use [simplejson](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson).

As shown by [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2119597) form [pkoch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5128/pkoch) you can use the following import statement to  get a json library depending on the installed python version:

```
try:
    import json
except ImportError:
    import simplejson as json
```

Comment: Thanks! There were so many json modules I wasn't sure which was the one used in Python 2.6.

Comment: Way late here, but how can you write a script to import either json or simplejson depending on the installed python version?

Comment: @Wells: `try: import json; except ImportError: import simplejson` -- Excuse the indentation errors.

Comment: I can't believe this answer got 60 upvotes before rene edited it into something decent

Answer (score 49):

To Wells and others:

> Way late here, but how can you write a script to import either json or simplejson depending on the installed python version?

Here's how:

`try:
    import json
except ImportError:
    import simplejson as json`

Comment: Well, I would do it the other way round because simplejson has a faster implementation. If you have simplejson at Python >= 2.6 you should preferably use it instead of json.

Comment: Each one uses the performance tinfoil hat one choses. I prefer the stdlib simply because it's the stdlib. Feel free to disagree and provide benchmarks so others can agree with you.

Comment: simplejson has a C extension, no need for a benchmark here ;-) If the C extension is not compiled (missing compiler on installation for example) it is exactly the same library. See http://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote the cjson 1.0.6 patch and my advice is don't use cjson -- there are other problems with cjson in how it handles unicode etc.  I don't think the speed of cjson is worth dealing with the bugs -- encoding/decoding json is usually a very small bit of the time needed to process a typical web request...

json in python 2.6+ is basically simplejson brought into the standard library I believe...

Answer (score 1):

I prefer cjson since it's much faster: http://www.vazor.com/cjson.html

Comment: I want to remain compatible with the default library provided with 2.6 though, otherwise I'd agree with you.

Answer (score -1):

I am programming in Python 2.5 as well and wanted a suitable library. Here is how I did it.

donwloaded the simplejson egg file called  simplejson-2.0.6-py2.5-linux-i686.egg from
http://pypi.python.org/simple/simplejson/

installed it using the command :

`sudo python ./ez_setup.py ./simplejson-2.0.6-py2.5-linux-i686.egg`

Then imported the json library into the script file by doing :

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/coolkid/Android/simplejson/simplejson-2.0.6-py2.5-linux-i686.egg")
try: import simplejson as json
except ImportError: print ("import error")
```

Answer (score -1):

[`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) is a *built-in module*, you don't need to install it with `pip`.

Comment: The first line of the documentation says: "New in version 2.6", and the question specifically ask for a module for Python 2.5