# how to add json library

Tags: python, json, macos, python-2.5

i am new to python, on my Mac, when i issue command

```
User:ihasfriendz user$ python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import json
ImportError: No module named json
```

I get error on  json. how to add this library? i'm using 2.5 (the default came with leopard)

Comment: You should correct the spelling mistake in the Python tag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python 2.5: JSON module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791561/python-2-5-json-module)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can also install simplejson.

If you have pip (see https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) as your Python package manager you can install simplejson with:

```
 pip install simplejson
```

This is similar to the comment of installing with easy_install, but I prefer pip to easy_install as you can easily uninstall in pip with "pip uninstall package".

Comment: Would highly recommend this method to install simplejson, takes 10 seconds: http://slackrw.wordpress.com/2010/04/04/simplejson-for-python-on-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 6):

AFAIK the json module was added in version 2.6, see [here](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html). I'm guessing you can update your python installation to the latest stable 2.6 from [this page](http://www.python.org/download/).

Comment: in that case, how to upgrade my existing 2.5 to 2.6?

Comment: An installer for Python 2.6.2 for Mac OS X is available here: http://python.org/ftp/python/2.6.2/python-2.6.2-macosx2009-04-16.dmg   Apparently the installer creates a "Python 2.6" folder in the Applications folder containing a script to update your PATH so that running "python" at the command line runs the newly-installed Python 2.6 instead of the system-default Python 2.5: http://superuser.com/questions/29652/how-do-i-properly-update-python-on-mac-os-x/30154#30154

Answer (score 2):

You can also install json-py from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/json-py/