# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'loads' while parsing json in python

Tags: python, json, python-2.5

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Shivam/Desktop/jsparse.py", line 13, in <module>
info = json.loads(str(data))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'loads'
```

Any thoughts what wrong I am doing here?

This is my code:

```
import json
import urllib
url = ''
uh = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = uh.read()
info = json.loads(str(data))
```

Comment: Works fine here. Are you sure you don't have another module named `json.py`?

Comment: Actually there is no json.py.There is one json.pyc

Comment: Ah, yeah, remove that. Don't name modules after Python builtin modules :)

Comment: That was inbuilt.I am using python 2.5.3 and json.pyc was already  present in the 'LIB' folder where python is installed.Should I delete that and then run the code?There is no json.py file in 'LIB'

Comment: Oh, no, don't mess with libraries included with the Python distribution. I meant, was there a module named `json` in your code. But now I've found your problem and will answer shortly.

Comment: Thanks for the help mate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're using Python 2.5.x, which doesn't have the `json` module. If possible, I recommend upgrading to Python 2.7.x, as 2.5.x is badly outdated.

If you need to stick with Python 2.5.x, you'll have to use the `simplejson` module (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791561/which-json-module-can-i-use-in-python-2-5)). This code will work for 2.5.x as well as newer Python versions:

```
try:
    import json
except ImportError:
    import simplejson as json
```

Or if you're only using Python 2.5, just do:

```
import simplejson as json
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice.I installed python 2.7 and it worked

Comment: No problem at all, glad to help! :) If this resolved your problem, please click the checkbox next to the answer to accept the answer and mark the question as resolved.