# "pip install json" fails on Ubuntu

Tags: python-2.7, pip, ubuntu-16.04

Cannot install the json module.
As far as I know I shouldn't use sudo. what's the matter?

```
 pip install json
The directory '/home/snow/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/snow/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting json
  Downloading json-99.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-YkvqVh/json/setup.py", line 2, in <module>
        raise RuntimeError("Package 'json' must not be downloaded from pypi")
    RuntimeError: Package 'json' must not be downloaded from pypi

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-YkvqVh/json/
```

Comment: What is not clear about `raise RuntimeError("Package 'json' must not be downloaded from pypi")`?

Comment: It should say something like "package is unnecessary" if that's what's happening. If I'm told I need to install a package, and the installer says I can't download it from X, a reasonable assumption is that I need to download it from somewhere else. But where?

Answer (score 113):

[`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) is a *built-in module*, you don't need to install it with `pip`.

Comment: It's a built-in module and you **can't** install it with `pip`. If you use ubuntu such as the user above, it might be you DO have python2 but you DON'T have json; see my answer.

Answer (score 14):

While it's true that `json` is a built-in module, I also found that on an Ubuntu system with `python-minimal` installed, you DO have `python` but you can't do `import json`. And then I understand that you would try to install the module using pip!

If you have `python-minimal` you'll get a version of python with less modules than when you'd typically compile python yourself, and one of the modules you'll be missing is the `json` module. The solution is to install an additional package, called `libpython2.7-stdlib`, to install all 'default' python libraries.

```
sudo apt install libpython2.7-stdlib
```

And then you can do `import json` in python and it would work!

Comment: Thank you very much for the insight @MichielB