# Buildozer Error With Json

Tags: android, python, json, ubuntu, buildozer

`pip install json` fails on ubuntu and gives errors [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41466431/6374964).

I am trying `buildozer android debug` on my Ubuntu machine and I have a dependency `json`. The problem is, `buildozer` is internally trying to install json and it is giving the exact same error:

`RuntimeError: Package 'json' must not be downloaded from pypi`

My `buildozer` is configured and I have no issues when I run it withour `json`.

Answer (score 2):

Since Json is built-in (as stated in the thread you linked to) you don't have to include it as a requirement.

Just change it in your buildozer.spec and it should work.

(I know, it's probably a bit late now ^^)